# Get Drupal views field values as html radio buttons

Tags: views

I am having a view page created for a node type. It is out putting the content in the page. In that there  is a field called options with multiple values per node. I want it to be outputted in the form of html options/radio button. Is there any way to do it?

Comment: are you wanting the viewer of the page to be able to select one of those radio buttons and have it saved back into the node or......what?

Comment: Are you talking about an exposed filter for the View or  are you just trying to theme a field in the View as radio buttons? If it's a field, what kind of widget is set on it now? Is it a select list?

Comment: I want to theme the field in the view as radio button. I will be using js to give it additional functionality.